# Mutable arrays as values in ES6 Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Does it make sense to use an array (which may be frequently push'ed and splice'd) as the value in an ES6 Map, or should I stick to plain associative arrays?

eg something like the following Node server code which would track which users have already downloaded a specific file

```
// initialisation
var map = new Map();
map.set ("foo.png",[]);

// push a new user id to array associated with hashString 
function userHasFile(filename,userId) {

    // retrieve array of all userIds that have downloaded the file
    var users = map.get(filename);

    // delete the map reference since we are going to update it
    map.delete(filename);

    // push the new userId to the array of users that have downloaded file
    users.push(userId);

    // update the Map key to the new array
    map.set(filename,users);
}

// example usage
userHasFile("foo.png","user1");
userHasFile("foo.png","user2");
```

I'm new to ES6 and the simplicity of the Map API appeals to me, so I'm wondering if there are any benefits\downsides (such as performance, memory, GC etc) to this approach over using standard associate arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely.

Having a key-list store is a useful enough pattern that it's one of [the data types in Redis](http://redis.io/topics/data-types).

Keeping an array in a Map is a totally legitimate and useful thing to do. It's a great way to store a list of objects that match some criteria and is especially efficient in JavaScript (and other languages that use references). The map doesn't actually hold a copy of the array, just a reference to it, so you can modify the array from outside of the map and the map will update without knowing or resizing.

However, you should be careful to use more functional patterns if they make sense. If you have incoming items, you may want to stream them into a map/reduce (using reduce to group them by key) rather than keeping a map and modifying the underlying arrays. You are relying on references and side effects here.

If you want to prevent the arrays from being updated at some point, you can replace them with immutable arrays, using a library like [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

If you're working in a server, say, with incoming requests that you need to record but you don't know when they will arrive (the kind of cache-and-flush that statsd does), a map makes sense:

```
let responses = new Map();

server.on('request', function (url, responseTime) {
  if (!responses.has(url)) {
    responses.set(url, []);
  }

  const times = responses.get(url);
  times.push(responseTime);
});

const flushTimer = setInterval(function () {
  stats.write(responses);
  responses = new Map();
}, 10*1000);
```